# Handling Incremental Updates in PySpark Structured Streaming with Add and Remove Operations

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm working with PySpark and Spark Structured Streaming and facing a challenge in handling incremental updates (additions and removals) in streaming data. My data stream contains records that represent either an addition (`op = 'w'`) or a removal (`op = 'd'`) of objects, as shown below:

```
ID    Object             op
1     {'a': {'a', 'b'}}  w
1     {'c': {'c', 'd'}}  w
1     {'a': {'a', 'b'}}  d
```

I want to group this data by `ID` and maintain a dynamic array of objects based on the `op` value. For additions (`w`), the object should be appended to the array, and for removals (`d`), the object should be removed if it matches a key in the array. The challenge arises when handling the removals over a long stream period.

For example, if the first two rows arrive, the expected grouped result is:

```py
ID    Object
1     [{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}]
```

However, I'm unsure how to update this result when a removal operation comes in later (like the third row in the example which should remove the a: {‘a’: ‘b’} object). Specifically, I'm looking for a way to:

1. Efficiently maintain the state of the grouped data over time.
2. Apply addition and removal operations based on matching keys in the existing state.

Could anyone suggest a way to handle this in PySpark Structured Streaming? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.